# First time using breadboard, diagram circuit and arduino

Tags: arduino, breadboard, diagram

I'm relatively new to Arduinos, schematic circuits, and breadboards. My goal is to recreate this [project](https://github.com/k3ng/k3ng_rotator_controller/wiki/210-Hardware-Schematic) that emulates an antenna rotator controller.

**To clarify, I don't want to use the LCD and button connections since they are irrelevant for my future projects, so I did not take them into account**

However, I'm not entirely sure if I've connected every cable in the correct positions. To simulate the circuit connections, I used Tinkercad.com. I own an Arduino Mega 2560 R3, so I believe that the pins simulated in Tinkercad and shown in the schematic circuit from the Github correspond to the Mega as well.

Note: I did not give values for the transistors, resistors and capacitors since I want to know If did it correctly and then I want to build it in real life

Edit: the external cables, that are labeled, are connected to this  [device](https://batima-electronic.com/notices/products/G-5500DC_IM_ENG_EBB70X101_1906V-BS.pdf) page 5 shows a table for external control and pins:

1. For elevation
2. For Azimuth
   2 - 5 are for roataion or up and down
3. Provides DC 13 V to 8 v
4. GND
   The circuit diagram looks like this:

[image]

My test looks like this.

Edit2: I rearranged everything
[image]

As I'm a beginner, I would like to know if I've made any mistakes. Feedback is appreciated!

Comment: you seem to miss a ground connection between the circuit and your Arduino.

Comment: @SimSon My bad, I edited my post and updated the screeshot

Comment: 1. There's no Vcc either to power the breadboard. 2. To check wiring is really something you need to learn, people will grow tired really quick otherwise. 3. For this particular circuit you can do this: put a resistor and led in series with every output, instead of the transistor etc. Then you run a sketch that sets a single led high, then next, and so on. This way you get visual that each pin corresponds to the function.

Comment: @MiNiMe Regarding your point 1. Do you mean like [this](https://batima-electronic.com/notices/products/G-5500DC_IM_ENG_EBB70X101_1906V-BS.pdf) ? I want to connect the breadboard to this device, in page 5 there is a table to connect the external pins and the schematic: Pin 7 "provides DC 13 V to 8 V at up to 100mA" this one is connected to my diagram "SpeedVoltage" Would that count as VCC?

Comment: The three capacitors (blue things) with leads in columns G and H are shorted as the five holes in a horizontal group are connected together.  Also the yellow wires from column F to the negative rail short the top lead of the transistors to ground.  The top lead of the transistors is the emitter, and should be grounded, but you seem to be using the top lead as collector.

Comment: @PeterBennett I made the modifications to the capacitors as requested. However, I'm having some difficulty understanding the issue with the cables from column F. Upon reviewing the Github project's diagram, I noticed that the emitter (bottom part) is grounded (the transistor in my setup is connected to the ground via yellow cables going to the right). Then, the collector has a connection or node to the rotation function and a capacitor that is also grounded. This configuration is causing some confusion for me.

Comment: I started like you with Fritzing, but you will realize that it's much better to start with an schematic like the one in the 1st image but for your concrete project, including the power lines for the arduino, all ground connections, etc. You can do it with kicad easily, or other tools.  Then and only then, when everything is clear, you can go to a physical design.  This way you can solve all the circuit aspects, check all the specs in the datasheets, ask here, and adjust/rewire what is needed easily. With Fritzing (and similar) is harder, slower and difficult to understand.

Comment: Buy the components and build the real circuit in a real breadboard. If you intend to build anything with more than one transistor, **forget Fritzing**.